# Как сайт может узнать с какой соц. сети (почты) зашел человек на PHP?

Tags: php

Суть вопроса:
Есть сайт на котором регистрируются через разные сервисы: yandex, mail, vk, facebook и т.д.
С быстрой регистрацией помогает https://ulogin.ru/ 
Так вот, мне надо узнать с какого сервиса заходит человек и применяя те или иные действия так, как для разных сервисов это разные действия, достать аватарку пользователя.
Если кратко, то мне надо достать аватарку пользователя из сервисов (yandex, mail, vk, facebook и т.д.).

Comment: Но ведь код для авторизации через эти самые сервисы у тебя же написан. И вот тот код точно знает кого и на основании чего он пустил

Comment: Не думаю, авторизация же идет с помощью https://ulogin.ru/

Comment: Ok. Заходим на ulogin.ru. "Настройки виджета" -> "Информация о пользователе". там про сеть через которую он авторизовался что то написано ...

Comment: Это есть. Но как достать аватар?

Comment: Смотрите документацию к сервису. Вся истина в документации

Comment: Да, всё сделал, спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не работал с сервисом, но как на странице получения виджета так и на страницах документации к нему все указанно.

1) Правильно настраиваем виджет (https://ulogin.ru/help.php#fields).

Т.к. вам необходима аватарка, необходимо добавить ключ **photo** или **photo_big** в параметр **fields** вашего виджета. Соответственно код для вставки будет примерно следующим

```
<script src="//ulogin.ru/js/ulogin.js"></script>
<div id="uLogin" data-ulogin="display=small;fields=first_name,last_name,photo_big,photo;providers=vkontakte,odnoklassniki,mailru,facebook;hidden=other;redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F"></div>
```

2) Получить необходимые данные ([Документация пункт 3](https://ulogin.ru/help.php#custom))

На вашем сайте, в страницу куда перенаправляет сервис, необходимо обработать пришедшие от сервиса данные, и запросить информацию о пользователе:

```
                $s = file_get_contents('http://ulogin.ru/token.php?token=' . $_POST['token'] . '&host=' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
                $user = json_decode($s, true);
                //$user['network'] - соц. сеть, через которую авторизовался пользователь
                //$user['identity'] - уникальная строка определяющая конкретного пользователя соц. сети
                //$user['photo_big'] - большое фото
                //$user['photo'] - фото 100х100
```

Если вы самостоятельно реализовывали регистрацию через данные сервис (не cms с плагином), то вы должны были получать токен от сервиса и запрашивать у него данные о пользователе ([Документация пункт 4](https://ulogin.ru/help.php#custom)), соответственно, вам достаточно добавить ключ в виджет, и вы увидите в массиве необходимые вам данные.